# Asyncio with Django

Tags: python, django, multithreading, loops, python-asyncio

I'm trying to use asyncio in my Django post processing like:

```
query : # a query to my model
tasks =  []        
for record in query:
    tasks.append(do_something_with_google_calendar(record))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
loop.close()
```

But I just get an error while executing:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-17'.
```

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance

Comment: How is defined the method do_something_with_google_calendar(record)

Comment: @asyncio.coroutine
def do_something_with_google_calendar( args ):

Comment: Why not use something like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) for post-processing? AsyncIO is not meant for post-processing, it's meant to be used with non-blocking IO.

Comment: I start to realize this.

Comment: I thought I could manage to access in an asynchronous way the _Google_ _Calendar_. 
I use _pythonanywhere_ server. I cannot use _Celery_ there. 
I will probably have to change to a new server.

Answer (score 7):

Your original code woun't work since get_event_loop() method is only shortcut to get_event_loop_policy().get_event_loop() which create&return event loop automatically for main thread only.
To make it work right you need to explicitly create and set new event loop for each current thread context:

```
query : # a query to my model
tasks =  []        
for record in query:
    tasks.append(do_something_with_google_calendar(record))

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
loop.close()
```

You may read more about this stuff [here](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2016/10/30/i-dont-understand-asyncio/).

Answer (score 2):

It looks that if I do like this, it works:

```
query : # a query to my model
tasks =  []        
for record in query:
    tasks.append(do_something_with_google_calendar(record))

loop = asyncio.SelectorEventLoop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
loop.close()
```

I hope it is stable and it will also work fine in UNIX as it does in Windows

Comment: Each separate thread expects its own asyncio event-loop since each loop takes over the thread's execution and schedules the async functions/ coroutines for it; therefore you can use `asyncio.new_event_loop()` to get a new event loop once in each thread, and then `get_event_loop()` will return the loop defined for that thread. (Your solution should work as well since `SelectorEventLoop` will return a new loop as well)